How to map a property to the right database columns, with the correct values, using the same transformations already defined in models
In my application I am adding filters in the frontend. The frontend will get a list of all possible values of a property to filter on. To get all possible values I get all distinct values from a column of the database.
var possibleNames = await Article.Select(x => x.Name).Distinct().ToListAsync();

When the filter is selected it can simply be added in the where clause.
var articles = await Article.Where(x => x.Name == name).ToListAsync();

The problem is that not all properties that are given to the frontend are columns in the database. To illustrate this I made an example for an article.
I have an application which has 3 classes for each model.

A database model for interacting with the database
A DTO model for internal use in the application
A view model for sending through an HTTP request

Each model has the potential to change properties when being created.
Enum Type {
    Magazine,
    Store
}

public class ArticleDB
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int LengthInMM { get; set; }
    public bool MagazineRack { get; set; }
    public bool StoreRack { get; set; }

    public ArticleDB(ArticleDTO dto)
    {
        Id = dto.Id;
        Name = dto.Name;
        lengthInMM = dto.LengthInMM;
        MagazineRack = dto.StoredIn == Type.Magazine;
        StoreRack = dto.StoredIn == Type.Store;
    }

    public ArticleDTO ToDTO() => new ArticleDTO()
    {
        Id = Id,
        Name = Name,
        LengthInMM = LengthInMM,
        StoredIn = MagazineRack ? Type.Magazine : Type.Store
    }
}

public class ArticleDTO
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int LengthInMM { get; set; }
    public Type StoredIn { get; set; }
}

public class ArticleView
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int LengthInM { get; set; }
    public string StoredIn { get; set; }

    public ArticleView(ArticleDTO dto)
    {
        Id = dto.Id;
        Name = dto.Name;
        LengthInM = dto.LengthInMM / 1000;
        StoredIn = dto.StoredIn.ToString();
    }

    public ArticleDTO ToDTO() => new ArticleDTO()
    {
        Id = Id,
        Name = Name,
        LengthInMM = LengthInM * 1000,
        StoredIn = StoredIn == "Magazine" ? Type.Magazine : Type.Store
    }
}

Is their a clean way to use these models to transform single properties to one or multiple columns and transform the value if needed for getting the possible values and for getting the filtered values?
Right now, if I want to filter on the LengthInM I have to transform this value in 3 different areas: when getting the values, when getting possible values, when filtering on value. And for StoredIn a custom check would need to be done in 3 different places aswell.

I'd consider throwing the DTO away for a start, and giving the job of mapping to a third class so that you don't have your separate data layers aware of each other..

..but I don't really understand the question. You store the length in mm in the db and use it in m in the UI, but you seem to be complaining that you have to convert it - if the conversion was just in one place then the operation that requires it in some unit would be given the converted object, not the source object, no? eg you have a FindByLength extension on your context; that would take a db entity not a viewmodel and pull the parameter out of it, then you can use your mapper to convert your viewmodel to the db entity the FindByLength requires and the conv code only exists in the mapper

(Or if find by length takes a primitive, map your viewmodel to an end, pull the length and pass it over)

@flackoverstow Thanks for replying. I know the project structure is not ideal for what I'm asking, but its the structure of the project I am working on. Could you give an example of what you mean by using a mapper?
